# Extracting binary char in a webservice response

Tags: apex-webservice

I am actually facing a problem with apex webservice response interpretation. In my response i have a mixture of string and binary data. I need only the binary part and discard all the rest, but I need to extract only the binary part and discard the other part, as i need to generate a PDF out of the response. The problem is that even if I know my delimeters,and try to dissect the binary part and write it into a file, the file is corrupted. Once i use string methods, the binary part get corrupted.

here is the sample response :

```
 --uuid:8c30c4fb-e424-42f9-9420-903c7e751482
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
  Content-ID: <f7f16548-37b4-45c9-9ca0-cce3ac43c4c4-3162@cxf.apache.org>
   .......................binary content start here............
   %PDF-1.4
   ...
   ...
   ...
   %%EOF
   .......................binary content end here............
   --uuid:8c30c4fb-e424-42f9-9420-903c7e751482--
```

I know that if i get the response in a blob, i would not be able to use the indexof or substring methods to extract the part i need. So how can I generate my pdf from the webservice response without the file been corrupted?

Comment: Looks to me like you have pretty clear identifiers to use to strip off the start and end of your content using a variety of string methods: `%PDF-1.4` and `%%EOF`.

Comment: If i use the string methods, the binary part get corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the getBodyAsBlob methods and not the getBody. Then try inserting the whole response as attachment or in document as per required, i think that the unnecessary part (string part) will not affect the pdf content.

Comment: this work fine :)